# Firefox has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Using ubuntu 22.04 cant use Firefox. Package missing, has been obsolete or is only available from another source.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 22.04, by default Firefox is installed as a `snap` package.

#### Reinstalling it via `snap`

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo snap install firefox
```

#### Installing it via `apt`

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: @VlastimilBurián yes, Firefox is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories. The PPA is maintained by the same people as the old Firefox package.

Comment: @VlastimilBurián I don't think that's true. The actual people running the PPA are literally the same people who always packaged firefox; this is actually more trustworthy than Canonical's snap. Not to mention that in my humble experience, it works better. Canonical really overshot the target quite a bit there with their snapification efforts. *Yes*, in general: I'd abstain from recommending using PPAs for software packaged by a distro, but in this case, *the software is actually no longer packaged by the distro maintainers*, anymore :(

Comment: Ok, I refrain from PPAs in general, but let's say do it your way...

Comment: @VlastimilBurián just came back to say that it's wise to in general be sceptical of unfiltered repositories of third-party packages. But that's exactly what the snap store is.

Comment: I had troubles apparently caused by snap so I was also trying to avoid the `snap` package.  The solution for installing via `apt` proposed by @sotirov (and many others) results in "Package firefox has no installation candidate."